# Insert separator row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm new to ASP.NET VB, and i'm having trouble and dont really understand the code of putting in row seperators in a gridview. I have 5 columns and the fifth columns rows field text is what i would like inserted into the new seperator row. There may be more than one per question. To populate my gridview i'm calling upon a stored procedure "Select_Problems" and carrying a persons name from another page through "SvarRecord" and matching it up with the SP @Name. The fifth column in the SP has four possibilities "1. Person upset?", "2. Is Person is resisting?", and so on. My code is as follows and i would like to have an easy way to do this but to make it look nice along with a color to divide each question. Thank you

```
 Public Sub LoadGrid2()

    Dim MyConn As New SqlConnection((ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Customer_Service").ConnectionString))
    Dim MyCmd As New SqlDataAdapter("Select_Problems", MyConn)

    MyCmd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    MyCmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar))
    MyCmd.SelectCommand.Parameters("@Name").Value = Session("SvarRecord")

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    MyConn.Open()
    MyCmd.Fill(ds, "Overview")
    GridView2.DataSource = ds
    GridView2.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I know your supposed to do this in the Rowdatabound of the Gridview but I dont understand the code behind it to do this which would be great to do.

Comment: you should work in design mode, and **TemplateFields**

Answer (score 0):

In the `RowDataBound` event, you could check the index of the row currently being bound and determine if it is the last row in a set of 5 and then apply styling to the row to give a visual cue of separation without actually generating a blank separator row, like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
' Add a visual separator via CSS border property to every 5th row
    If e.Row.RowIndex Mod 5 = 0 Then
        ' Apply style to each cell in the row
        For Each cell As TableCell In e.Row.Cells
            cell.Attributes.Add("Style", "border-bottom: red 5px solid")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> Note: My math might be off by one so you may need to change the styling to the top of the row (`border-top` instead of `border-bottom`), but the idea is the same.

Comment: I've corrected my question, i need to decipher between the filtered data i'm bringing in. So all question 1's would be seperate from the other questions and the question would be at the top of each seperation of question.

Comment: @shawnmattson - so you are trying to group your data together by question number?

Comment: Yes i would like to group by question ("1. Person upset?", "2. Is Person is resisting?", and so on) Here's an example i'm aiming at.                                                                  http://i3.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/27fig05VB.png?cdn_id=2013-11-25-001

Comment: I do not think the `GridView` control is the best solution for this grouping idea, try Googling `ASP.NET nested repeater grouping data` for some leads.